# Recursive projects includes in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have two several projects and thinking about migrating them to Gradle from Maven. They have the following directory structure:

```
+ A 
  + A-submodule 1
  + A-submodule 2
  + B
     + B-submodule 1
     + B-submodule 2
     + build.gradle
     + settings.gradle
  + build.gradle
  + build.gradle
```

Project B depends on module from the project A. I want to include all the modules and the whole project A from A to B. How can I do this?

I tried following advice from this question: [Gradle - Recursively include external project and its subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770024/gradle-recursively-include-external-project-and-its-subprojects) with code like this in settings.gradle:

```
include '../'
apply from '../settings.gradle'
project(':../').projectDir = new File(rootDir, '../')
```

But it doesn't work. Gradle thinks that the modules from the project A reside in the directory of the project B.

Is it possible to solve this problem?